# Storing time strings to TIME column in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, time, php-carbon

I use a timepicker to get a time string(eg: '1:00am' or '12:00pm'). I need to modify and store this in a mysql **TIME** data type column as eg: '12:00:00'. Now, since the **TIME** column stores in 24 hrs format, I need to "modify" it. I can't seem to find any help to modify using Carbon, since I'm not using any dates. I'm using a mutator in **Laravel**, but would like to know if there is a better way like using **Carbon** for dates.

```
public function setTimeAttribute($time) {
    if(substr($time, -2, 0) == 'am') {
        // do nothing
    } else if(substr($time, -2, 0) == 'pm') {
        // increase hours.ie: 1:00pm to 13:00:00
    }
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use PHP `strtotime()` function.

```
$time = "12:00am";

$timestamp = strtotime($time);

echo $timestamp;

//Will print something like: 1469228400
```

Or any other date format you prefer.

It's best to store time as timestamp, to convert it back you can use date() function.
E.g: `$value = date("H:i:s", $timestamp);`